# Jade ternary/condition for element attribute

Tags: express, pug

I'm trying to use a jade ternary or condition to control whether or not an element has an attribute, but am not getting anything to work.

This would just let me set the value of the attribute, but I can't remove it entirely:

```
select(
  required=(field.required ? 'required' : '')
)
```

And this is invalid:

```
select(
 (field.required ? 'required' : '')
)
```

I need to find a way to nest the condition because there's a lot of other attributes, and I don't want to duplicate them in two if/else blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Jade will render boolean HTML5 attributes based off of a boolean variable value: `required=true` or `required=false`, and will not render the attribute if the variable is false.

Set the attribute to a boolean value, rather than to a string value. The attribute will not render if the variable is false.

```jade
select(required=field.required)
```

Comment: The title is "Jade ternary/condition for element attribute". 
It is cool that you managed to help the author, but this doesn't answer the question of the title. You're just fixing the very specific case of boolean attribute.

What if I want to add a class "on" or "off" based on a boolean? What if I want to pre-fill a value for a text input based on a boolean?